# Finding distance between current location and the inputted latitude and longitude

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I am new to flutter programming and have tried out a small project.
I am getting latitude and longitude from the user and finding distance between the current location and the given latitude and longitude

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';



void main() {
 runApp(Myapp());
} 

class Myapp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override

  _MyappState createState() => _MyappState();
}

class _MyappState extends State<Myapp> {
  double a,b;
  double distanceInMeters;

  String result;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('location'),),
        body: Container(
        color: Colors.teal,
        width: double.infinity,
        child:Column(

          children:<Widget>[
            TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration:InputDecoration(icon: Icon(Icons.add_location)),
              onSubmitted:(lat1) {
                print(lat1);
                a=lat1 as double ;
              } ,
            ),
            TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration:InputDecoration(icon: Icon(Icons.add_location)),
              onSubmitted:(long1) {
                print(long1);
                b=long1 as double ;
              },
             ),
            FlatButton(
            color: Colors.orange,
            onPressed: () async {
             final position=await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: 
              LocationAccuracy.high);

              distanceInMeters = await 
              Geolocator().distanceBetween(position.latitude,position.longitude,a,b);
              print(distanceInMeters);

            },
            child: Text(
              "Flat Button",
            ),
          ),
            Text('$distanceInMeters')



        ],
        ),



      ),

     ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYQcM.png)

but the output is always null in the app, does it have to do with no of decimals after the point in the inputted latitude and longitude??
what should I do to improve my code,
can u guys find the error and suggest me??

Comment: first step - check the values of `position.latitude,position.longitude,a,b`

Comment: position.latitude and position.longitude is coming out fine, without any error.and a,b is just something we get as input so there is no error in that too.i checked all four outputs